# Search for a column in database table and add the values to a datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I want to search for the value where `item = 'apple'` and then add the entire column to a DataGridView in VB.net form application. I use following code lines to do my task, but the output i get is a blank data cell.

```
Dim table As DataTable = myTable.Tables("fruits")

    Dim expression, item As String

    expression = "item = 'apple'"
    Dim foundRows() As DataRow

    foundRows = table.Select(expression)

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("item")
    dt.Columns.Add("price")

    Dim row1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

    For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
        row1.Item("ID") = row(0)
        row1.Item("item") = row(1)
        row1.Item("price") = row(2)

    Next

    dt.Rows.Add(row1)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as this... you should add columns in-order to add rows as u expect

```
Dim table As DataTable = myTable.Tables("fruits")

Dim expression As String

expression = "item = 'apple'"
Dim foundRows() As DataRow

foundRows = table.Select(expression)

Dim col, col1, col2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

col.HeaderText = "ID"
col1.HeaderText = "Item"
col2.HeaderText = "Price"

DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1)
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col2)

    For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row(0), row(1), row(2))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the row to add once (row1) and looping through foundRows and assigning same var (row1) and then adding it only once to the DG, this will results in adding only the last found item.

Change your code starting from "`Dim row1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow`" to be:

```
    For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
        Dim row1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

        row1.Item("ID") = row(0)
        row1.Item("item") = row(1)
        row1.Item("price") = row(2)

        dt.Rows.Add(row1)
    Next
```

I'm not sure if this is the only reason, but give it a try :)

Comment: that's weird, I tired it and it's working. While debugging your code, is foundRows var being filled with results? its length should be > 0